# Fade in/out label on hover

Tags: jquery

I have couple areas with labels. When I hover an area I would like to change the color of the label in that area to be more prominent and fade out the other labels in the areas that I am not hovering over.

How do I do that swap?

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".label").fadeOut(100);
});
```

Comment: Please post your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass two functions to `.hover`. The first one will be used as a callback to mouseover, the second one to mouseout:

```
$("li").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(".label").fadeOut(100);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find(".label").fadeIn(100);
    }
);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/ExWQp/1/. If you mouse-over the list-items quickly you can create a queue of animations that look like each label is blinking.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you pass two functions into `.hover()`. The first is the `mouseover` function and the second is the `mouseout` function.

JS --

```
$("li").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find("label").stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find("label").stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
    }
);
```

CSS --

```
label {
    opacity : 0;
    filter  : alpha(opacity=0);
}​
```

The `.stop()` will allow the user to quickly mouse-over then out and the animation will not run all the way though, which creates a queue of animations if the user mouse overs and out a bunch fast. I used `.fadeTo()` with the `.stop()` because if you use `.fadeOut()`/`.fadeIn()` the animation can break when the user mouse overs and out quickly.

Another advantage to `.fadeTo()` is that we are only animating the `opacity` of the element, so the element still retains its position on the screen (i.e. elements don't jump around).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/ExWQp/

Docs for `.hover()`: http://api.jquery.com/hover

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    // hover active
  }, 
  function () {
    // hover deactive
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this example for you.
It uses unordered list, with *<span>* tags inside, which are faded in/out.

```
<ul>
    <li><span>1st.</span> list item</li>
    <li><span>2nd.</span> list item</li>
    <li><span>3dr.</span> list item</li>
    <li><span>4th.</span> list item</li>
    <li><span>5th.</span> list item</li>
    <li><span>6th.</span> list item</li>
    <li><span>7th.</span> list item</li>
</ul>​
```

```
$('li').mouseenter(function(){
    $('span', this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 150)
    $('span', $(this).siblings('li')).stop().animate({opacity:0.3}, 150)
})
```

When you *hover* the LI element, child *span* is faded to 100% and child *spans* of sibling LIs are faded to 50%;

```
$('ul').mouseleave(function(){
    $('span', this).animate({opacity: 1}, 150);
})​
```

When you leave parent UL element, all *span* elements are reverted back, animated to 100%;

Here is working example of this...
http://jsfiddle.net/HBj4F/